# Почему раскодирование base85 из примера википедии происходит с ошибкой: "ValueError: bad base85 character at position 25"?

Tags: python

Строку в base85 я взял из оригинальной [статьи](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85).

```
import base64

text = r'''<~9jqo^BlbD-BleB1DJ+*+F(f,q/0JhKF<GL>Cj@.4Gp$d7F!,L7@<6@)/0JDEF<G%<+EV:2F!,
O<DJ+*.@<*K0@<6L(Df-\0Ec5e;DffZ(EZee.Bl.9pF"AGXBPCsi+DGm>@3BB/F*&OCAfu2/AKY
i(DIb:@FD,*)+C]U=@3BN#EcYf8ATD3s@q?d$AftVqCh[NqF<G:8+EV:.+Cf>-FD5W8ARlolDIa
l(DId<j@<?3r@:F%a+D58'ATD4$Bl@l3De:,-DJs`8ARoFb/0JMK@qB4^F!,R<AKZ&-DfTqBG%G
>uD.RTpAKYo'+CT/5+Cei#DII?(E,9)oF*2M7/c~>'''

print(base64.b85decode(text.encode()))
```

---

Кодирование того текста создает base85, сильно отличающийся от примерочного:

```
text = 'Man is distinguished, not only by his reason, but by this singular passion from other animals, which is a lust of the mind, that by a perseverance of delight in the continued and indefatigable generation of knowledge, exceeds the short vehemence of any carnal pleasure.'
text = base64.b85encode(text.encode()).decode()
print(text)
```

Результат кодирования в base85:

```
O<`^zX>%ZCX>)XGZfA9Ab7*B`EFf-gbRchTY<VDJc_3(Mb0BhMVRLV8EFfZabRc4RAarPHb0BkRZfA9DVR9gFVRLh7Z*CxFa&K)QZ**v7av))DX>DO_b1WctXlY|;AZc?TVIXXEb95kYW*~HEWgu;7Ze%PVbZB98AYyqSVIXj2a&u*NWpZI|V`U(3W*}r`Y-wj`bRcPNAarPDAY*TCbZKsNWn>^>Ze$>7Ze(R<VRUI{VPb4$AZKN6WpZJ3X>V>IZ)PBCZf|#NWn^b%EFfigV`XJzb0BnRWgv5CZ*p`Xc4cT~ZDnp_Wgu^6AYpEKAY);2ZeeU7aBO8^b9HiME&
```

---

Если кодировать и раскодировать только средствами модуля base64, тогда проблем не возникает

Comment: А какие алфавиты используются для кодирования и декодирования?

Comment: По умолчанию используется utf-8

Comment: Ну, допустим, с кодировкой разобрались. А алфавиты какие?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, из модуля: `_b85alphabet = (b"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                b"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!#$%&()*+-;<=>?@^_`{|}~")`

Comment: А в примере из Wiki он же?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, вроде бы да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимательное чтение википедии и документации к модулю `base64` даёт понимание, что:

- Base85 и Ascii85 это разные вещи
- Ascii85 бывает тоже разный, и в данном примере это его Adobe-версия (`<~` в начале и `~>` в конце)

---

```
>>> print(base64.a85decode(text.encode(), adobe=True))
b'Man is distinguished, not only by his reason, but by this singular passion from other animals, which is a lust of the mind, that by a perseverance of delight in the continued and indefatigable generation of knowledge, exceeds the short vehemence of any carnal pleasure.'
```

---

```
>>> print(base64.a85decode(text[2:-2].encode()))
b'Man is distinguished, not only by his reason, but by this singular passion from other animals, which is a lust of the mind, that by a perseverance of delight in the continued and indefatigable generation of knowledge, exceeds the short vehemence of any carnal pleasure.'
```

---

С кодированием тоже всё в порядке:

```
>>> source_text = 'Man is distinguished, not only by his reason, but by this singular passion from other animals, which is a lust of the mind, that by a perseverance of delight in the continued and indefatigable generation of knowledge, exceeds the short vehemence of any carnal pleasure.'
>>> print(base64.a85encode(source_text.encode(), adobe=True) == text.replace('\n', '').encode())
True
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вы правы, меня смутила фраза `"...Ascii85, also called Base85..."`, поэтому я решил что это одно и тоже

Comment: @gil9red есть предположение, что это косяк в википедии, который надо исправить) Но я с этими кодировками дела не имел, их истории не знаю и от каких-либо действий воздержусь